# HTML / CSS Unclickable image & Un-copyable text

Tags: html, css

Ok i have a image that when you click you go to a certain url (direct link or somthing like that)
Also i have a box under it with text in it,
For some reason that image is un-clickable and the box with the text below is not able to be copied(the text of course not the box),

The image was fine & clickable until i positioned it with CSS then it would not work,
The text box under is also positioned with CSS
But i dont know why that would make it un-clickable and un-copy-able
Here is the css to the image and the text box

```
    }
#left{
width:120px;
height:auto;
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:150px;
}
```

And here is the HTML code for the image and text box

```
    <div id="left"> <a href="user.php" target="_blank" align="right"><img src="img/acc.png"></a></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="boxes">
<div id="left">
<div id="box-top-green">Users & Ranks</div>
<div id="box-centro">
                    <p>MxS II Tankz (Leader)
                    </p>MxS II Tacks (Co Leader)
                    <p> MxS II xTech (Tech) 
                    </p> MxS II --- 
                    <p> MxS II --- 
                    </p> MxS II --- 
                    <p> MxS II --- 
                    </p>MxS II --- 
                    <p> MxS II --- 
                    </p> MxS II --- 
                    <p> MxS II ---
</div>
<div id="box-abajo"></div>





</div>
```

can anyone help please

Whole code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>MxS Offical Website</title>
<link href="./css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./css/box.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body>
<div id="nav">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">xTech</a>
<div class="menu">utubeuser</div>
<div class="menu">utubeuser</div>
<div class="menu">utubeuser</div>
<div class="menu">utubeuser</div>
<div class="menu">utubeuser</div>
</div>


<div id="header"><div style="position:absolute; top:46px; left:50px">
<br><br>


<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mxs-Clan/474428962653273?ref=hl" target="_blank" align="right"><img src="http://www.niftybuttons.com/3d/facebook.png"></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" align="left"><img src="http://www.niftybuttons.com/3d/youtube.png"></a>


<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>



<div id="right">
<div id="box_top_green">MxS - Be Apart Of The Experiance</div>

<div id="box_centro">MxS (MircoXGaming, is a "sniping clan we play various call of duty games 
Such As <br> MW2, Black ops 1 & Black ops 2 and more <br> We are currently explanding over both console 
<br> Xbox 360, And Playstation 3, Some of our clan members have even pre - ordered PS4 And XBOX One 
But Lets get down to the point, If you want to be apart of the "Clan" there a a few step you have to go through
<br> First you need to go to the try out page, You should find the link in the red bar above
<br> And on the try out page further instructions will be there, Thanks -MxS xTech<br></div>


<div id="box_abajo"></div>
<div id="box_top_green">MxS - A Elite Sniping Clan - MicroXGaming</div>

<div id="box_centro"><object width="640" height="360">
  <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/ppTnSl7Fi7Q?version=3"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/ppTnSl7Fi7Q?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360"></embed>
</object></div>
<div id="box_abajo"></div>
</div>
</div>



<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="left"> <a href="user.php" target="_blank" align="right"><img src="img/acc.png"></a></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="boxes">
<div id="left">
<div id="box-top-green">Users & Ranks</div>
<div id="box-centro">
                    <p>MxS II Tankz (Leader)
                    </p>MxS II Tacks (Co Leader)
                    <p> MxS II xTech (Tech) 
                    </p> MxS II --- 
                    <p> MxS II --- 
                    </p> MxS II --- 
                    <p> MxS II --- 
                    </p>MxS II --- 
                    <p> MxS II --- 
                    </p> MxS II --- 
                    <p> MxS II ---
</div>
<div id="box-abajo"></div>





</div>



<br><br><br><br>

</head>
<body>

<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>



<div id="footer">Site Made By xTech - Zac<div style="width:300px; float:right;">All rights to there respective owners</div></div>


</body>
```

Box.css

```
#boxes{
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin:auto;
margin-top:35px;
}
#left{
width:120px;
height:auto;
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:150px;
}
#right{
width:600px;
height:auto;
float:left;
margin-top:-238px;
margin-left:510px;
}
#box-top-green{
background-image:url(../img/box-top-green.png);
width:307px;
height:28px;
margin:auto;
float:left;
font-family:Volter; font-size:9px; color:#FFFFFF; text-transform:uppercase;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000, -1px -1px #000000, 1px -1px #000000, -1px 1px #000000;
padding-left:18px; padding-top:22px;
margin-top:10px;
}
#box-top-yellow{
background-image:url(../img/box-top-yellow.png);
width:307px;
height:28px;
margin:auto;
float:left;
font-family:Volter; font-size:9px; color:#FFFFFF; text-transform:uppercase;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000, -1px -1px #000000, 1px -1px #000000, -1px 1px #000000;
padding-left:18px; padding-top:22px;
margin-top:10px;
}
#box-top-violet{
background-image:url(../img/box-top-violet.png);
width:307px;
height:28px;
margin:auto;
float:left;
font-family:Volter; font-size:9px; color:#FFFFFF; text-transform:uppercase;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000, -1px -1px #000000, 1px -1px #000000, -1px 1px #000000;
padding-left:18px; padding-top:22px;
margin-top:10px;
}
#box-centro{
background-image:url(../img/box-centro.png);
width:315px;
height:auto;
margin:auto;
float:left;
overflow:auto;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
}
#box-abajo{
background-image:url(../img/box-abajo.png);
width:325px;
height:6px;
margin:auto;
float:left;
}
#box_top_violet{
background-image:url(../img/box_top_violet.png);
width:645px;
height:28px;
margin:auto;
float:left;
font-family:Volter; font-size:9px; color:#FFFFFF; text-transform:uppercase;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000, -1px -1px #000000, 1px -1px #000000, -1px 1px #000000;
padding-left:18px; padding-top:22px;
margin-top:10px;
}
#box_top_green{
background-image:url(../img/box_top_green.png);
width:645px;
height:28px;
margin:auto;
float:left;
font-family:Volter; font-size:9px; color:#FFFFFF; text-transform:uppercase;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000, -1px -1px #000000, 1px -1px #000000, -1px 1px #000000;
padding-left:18px; padding-top:22px;
margin-top:10px;
}
#box_centro{
background-image:url(../img/box_centro.png);
width:653px;
height:4000;
margin:auto;
float:left;
overflow:auto;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
}
#box_abajo{
background-image:url(../img/box_abajo.png);
width:663px;
height:6px;
margin:auto;
float:left;
}
```

Index.css

```
body{
margin-top:0;
margin:auto;
background-image:url(../img/bg.png);
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
}
@font-face {
    font-family:Volter;
    src: url(./volter.ttf);
}

.menu{ display: inline;}
.menu{padding:8px 8px 14px 6px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; font-family:Volter; font-size:9px; text-shadow: 0px -1px #000000, 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px #000000;}

#header{
background-image:url(../img/banner.png);
width:100%;
height:89px;
margin:auto;
}
#nav{
background-image:url(../img/nav.png);
width:97.6%;
height:20px;
margin:auto;
font-family:Volter;
color:#000000;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:30px;
}
#footer{
background-image:url(../img/footer.png);
width:3336;
height:27px;
margin:auto;
font-family:Volter; font-size:9px; color:#FFFFFF; text-transform:uppercase;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000, -1px -1px #000000, 1px -1px #000000, -1px 1px #000000;
padding-left:8px; padding-top:8px;
}
```

**I created a fiddle for you, to help other visualize the problem. I've changed the image URL to something public. Feel free to edit this fiddle if you feel the need. Eric MORAND.**

http://jsfiddle.net/z7RhQ/

Comment: check with developer tools if you have another div on top of it that you don't see with just looking

Comment: I do not think so ill add the whole code ;)

Comment: Is that the same file/page? you have strange body and head tags in the middle of the page.

Comment: Are you sure that is all the code? Apart from the strange head and body tags there doesn't really seem to be anything wrong.

Comment: Serigo, i do not think so because the "MXS - BE APART OF THE EXPERIANCE" Box can be copied and there in the same "tags"                       Putvande thats all the code beside the css want to see the css?

Comment: Putvande, added both .css

Comment: Added a fiddle to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the problem comes from the fact that your #left div is overlapped by the first child of the #header div. This first child (let's call it TheDiv) is absolutely positioned, top at 46px and left at 50px. It contains a div (#right) that is 600px wide, 585px high and has a left margin of 510px. Thus, TheDiv is sized 1110px (600 + 510) x 710px (585 + looooot of `<br>`) by the layout engine.

Being absolutely positioned, it overlaps anything located inside this huge rectangle of 1110 x 710px.

I believe your layout is seriously flawed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You have an absolutely positioned div over that text.

`#header>div` has this css.

```
position:absolute; top:46px; left:50px
```

It should be.

```
position:absolute; top:46px; left:560px
```

---

It has a child (`#right`) with a margin-left of 510px.  That should be 0.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z7RhQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe I've found a solution to that problem.

I have changed the HTML structure, so I positioned a link (with the text) over the image, that doesn't have the link.

The image is in the back of the content div added with the css `background-image:...;`

This is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="text">
   <a href="#">Text copy here</a>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.text {
border:1px solid black;
width:300px;
height:200px;
display:table;
background-image:url(http://www.starcoppe.it/images/grafica-immagine-b.jpg);
background-size:300px 200px;
}

.text a{
content:'';
display:table-cell;
margin:0 auto;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}
```

Anyway watch the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/9zE2R/).